# htaccess redirect 404 page to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have changed my website & the url structure.
Now i want to redirect my old pages(currently it is 404 error pages) to my home page.

URL:

```
http://www.example.com/abc-def-ghi-sp(m).html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com
```

I have used the following rule in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

The above rule is working fine.
And i also need another redirection.But it is not working

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?name=amca&PID=143&PageID=abc
```

to

```
http://www.example.com
```

I have used the following rule in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php / [L,R=301]
```

But the result

It is showing the home page.

But the url in the browser is

```
http://www.example.com/?name=amca&PID=143&PageID=abc
```

I have tried different rule.But not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a **?** at the end of the target url.

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php /? [L,R=301]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important as it discards the orignal query strings.

This will redirect /fill.php?foo=bar to / without appending the old querystrings.

**Clear your browser's cache before testing this.**

If you want to redirect a spacific url with querystrings ,

You may try

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=foo&u=bar$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^file.php$ /? [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect a specific url /file.php?q=foo&u=bar to /

Answer (score 0):

Try `^page\.php*$ / [L,R=301]`

You were matching just the pattern you were interested in, and the engine will replace only the matched part. So you should match everything after the interested pattern for the sake of it being a victim of replacement.

The "*" matches everything after "php" and "$" is for signifying end of string.